# Python execute command line,sending input and reading output

Tags: python, io

How to achieve the following functionality:

1. Python executes a shell command, which waits for the user to `input` something
2. after the user typed the `input`, the program responses with some `output`
3. Python captures the `output`

Comment: Take a look at [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: In a more general case [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/python/pexpect/) might be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want `subprocess.Popen`.  To communicate with the process, you'd use the `communicate` method.

e.g.

```
process=subprocess.Popen(['command','--option','foo'],
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
inputdata="This is the string I will send to the process"
stdoutdata,stderrdata=process.communicate(input=inputdata)
```

Comment: What if i have 2 or more inputs and i want to run it in background so that i should see no console.

Answer (score 1):

For sync behaviors, you can use [**`subprocess.run()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function starting from `Python v3.5`.

As mentioned in [What is the difference between subprocess.popen and subprocess.run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187886/what-is-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-subprocess-run) 's accepted answer:

> The main difference is that *`subprocess.run`* executes a command and waits for it to finish, while with *`subprocess.Popen`* you can continue doing your stuff while the process finishes and then just repeatedly call `subprocess.communicate` yourself to pass and receive data to your process.