# What is the difference between subprocess.popen and subprocess.run

Tags: python

I'm new to the `subprocess` module and the documentation leaves me wondering what the difference is between `subprocess.popen` and `subprocess.run`.  Is there a difference in what the command does?  Is one just newer?  Which is better to use?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

[`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) [was added in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#subprocess) as a simplification over [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) when you just want to execute a command and wait until it finishes, but you don't want to do anything else in the mean time. For other cases, you still need to use `subprocess.Popen`.

The main difference is that `subprocess.run()` executes a command and **waits** for it to finish, while with `subprocess.Popen` you can continue doing your stuff while the process finishes and then just repeatedly call [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) yourself to pass and receive data to your process. Secondly, `subprocess.run()` returns [`subprocess.CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess).

`subprocess.run()` just wraps `Popen` and `Popen.communicate()` so you don't need to make a loop to pass/receive data or wait for the process to finish.

Check [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) for info on which params `subprocess.run()` pass to `Popen` and `communicate()`.

Answer (score 8):

Both available in Python by default.

The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle. For more advanced use cases, the underlying Popen interface can be used directly.

**-Subprocess.run**:

```
import subprocess
import sys

result = subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-c", "print('ocean')"])
```

**-Subprocess.popen**: run multiple command line with subprocess, communicate method waits for the process to finish and finally prints the stdout and stderr as a tuple

EX:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(shell_cmd,
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                     text = True,
                     shell = True
                     )
std_out, std_err = process.communicate()
std_out.strip(), std_err
```