# Why am i getting a host not found error when running my python ping script?

Tags: python, ping

i made this script a while ago and it was working if i remember correctly but now i get a could not find host error. Any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import socket
import sqlite3
import subprocess




BASE = Tk()
BASE.geometry("400x400")




def PING_CLIENT():
    
    HOST = PING_ENTRY

    command = "ping {} 30 -t".format(HOST)
    subprocess.run(command)
    
    


PING = ttk.Button(BASE, text="Ping IP", command=PING_CLIENT)
                  
PING.place(x=35, y=100, height=30, width=150)

PING_ENTRY = ttk.Entry(BASE)
PING_ENTRY.place(x=200, y=100, height=30, width=150)


BASE.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the value of `HOST`?  How do you know it is valid?

Comment: @ScottHunter i think you mean how do i know that the ip i entered is valid, and i used 8.8.8.8

Comment: @DineshKumar my code is meant to ping the ip entered in the IP_ENTRY box, and i tried doing that anyway and no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the value of your Entry widget. To do this, call the `get()` method on the widget. You can read more about the [Tkinter Entry Widget here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Example:

`HOST = PING_ENTRY.get()`

Also, I'm not exactly sure what the "30" in your command is supposed to do. If you intend for it to ping 30 times, you need to add the `-n` switch beforehand (on Windows) or `-c` switch (on most Linux distributions). For example, on Windows:

`command = "ping {} -n 30 -t".format(HOST)`

Comment: Thank you, i had a few versions of this and i imagine i deleted the one that had this included when i cleared some stuff out.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother again but i was trying to add a stop ping button with 
def PING_STOP():

    subprocess.Popen.terminate()

dont know what else to add to get it to work, im not the best lol

Comment: Just saw your reply now. It looks like @DineshKumar might have already answered this in his answer. But if you're still stuck just let me know and I'll see what I can do to help!

Comment: His method works but i would like to be able to use a button to stop the ping. :)

Comment: To do this, I would recommend using `subprocess.Popen` instead so you can get a reference to the process, then terminate it. Crude working example: https://pastebin.com/ea13QedA

Answer (score 1):

@AndroidNoobie's answer works fine. I am adding this just in case you want the execution to be async, you could use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `subprocess.run`.

The UI freezes until the `run` execution is complete. If you don't want that to happen, I would recommend using `subprocess.Popen`

```
def PING_CLIENT():

    HOST = PING_ENTRY.get()

    command = "ping {} -n 30  -t".format(HOST)
    #subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
    subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

From another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187886/what-is-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-subprocess-run#:%7E:text=The%20main%20difference%20is%20that,receive%20data%20to%20your%20process.):
The main difference is that `subprocess.run` executes a command and waits for it to finish, while with `subprocess.Popen` you can continue doing your stuff while the process finishes and then just repeatedly call subprocess.communicate yourself to pass and receive data to your process.

**EDIT:** Added code to make the ping stop after 30 trials.

To make your code stop after a specific number of packets use the below code.

Windows:

```
    command = "ping -n 30 {}".format(HOST)
    pro = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(pro.communicate()[0]) # prints the stdout
```

Ubuntu:

```
    command = "ping -c 30 {}".format(HOST)
    pro = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(pro.communicate()[0]) # prints the stdout
```

-t basically pings indefinitely in windows.That's why you weren't able to stop it.

Comment: Thank you that was the next thing i was working on fixing, saved me some time there. Is there a way to stop the ping ? if so please let me know, this is the first time ive used this site and the community is great, thanks to everyone that replied

Comment: Glad to be of help.Could you please let us know what is that 30 in your `command`?  What is it that you are trying to implement in this app exactly?

Comment: it was to make it stop the ping after 30 replies but i lost the code that was originally working so obviously that was messed up

Comment: @iHateThisShit I have edited the code with your ask. Try this and let me know if it worked :)