# subprocess unzip with source file remove?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, unzip

I'm using python subprocess to unzip a zip archive. My code is as below:

```
subprocess.Popen(['unzip', '{}.zip'.format(inputFile), '-d', output_directory])
```

Is there an unzip command to remove the zip source file after unzipping it? If no, how can I pipe an `rm` to the `subprocess.Popen` but to make sure it waits for the file to unzip first?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the `zipfile` library? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python

Here's a linked answer on how to remove files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder-in-python

Comment: In addition, prefer use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen` if your python version allows it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187984/6555423 or [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: well I will go with os.remove I just want to make sure it will remove the file only after it is extracted that is why I wanted to popen it to subprocess

Comment: What does making sure it will remove the file only after it is extracted have to do with using `subprocess`?

Comment: @Kaz my python is 2.7

Comment: @martineau I'm new to python, I'm asking.

Comment: Popen execute a child program in a new process, but not waits its end. You should do this with `wait()` if you will that. See [Popen docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: OK. `subprocess` is for starting new processes that can run in parallel with your Python script. If you want to wait for a started process to complete (so you can delete a file it uses for example), you can use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) in Python 2.7. Note however if your script has nothing else to do but wait, there isn't any reason to be using `subprocess` since you can unzip files with the `zipfile` module.

Comment: Or you can also use `subprocess.call` to have wait for command to complete.

Comment: This post explains subrocess.Popen and subprocess.call: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2837319/6555423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `&&` in the Shell, which will execute the second command only if the first was successful:

```
import subprocess
import os

values = {'zipFile': '/tmp/simple-grid.zip', 'outDir': '/tmp/foo'}
command = 'unzip {zipFile} -d {outDir} && rm {zipFile}'.format(**values)
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
_ = proc.communicate()

print('Success' if proc.returncode == 0 else 'Error')
```

Or, `os.remove()` if `unzip` succeeded:

```
inputFile = values['zipFile']
output_directory = values['outDir']

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['unzip', '{}'.format(inputFile), '-d', output_directory]
)
_ = proc.communicate()  # communicate blocks!

if proc.returncode == 0:
    os.remove(values['zipFile'])
print('Success' if not os.path.exists(inputFile) else 'Error')
```

Comment: I will check it and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: why is there  shell=True in the first suggestion and not in the second? I'm trying to avoid  shell=True.

Comment: I was unsure if `&&` does work correctly without `shell`.

Comment: The second solution without shell=True works well thanks.