# How to use subprocess.run to run sql from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb, subprocess, mariadb-10.3

I'm trying to get a Python script to work that downloads a file and then loads the data into a mariadb. My best option seems to be using `subprocess.run`, as I cannot update the Python version to a version that includes the new mariadb connector.

I've tried different options:

```
subprocess.run(["mysql", "-u" + mdb_usr, "-p" + mdb_pwd, "database", " < " + file.sql])
subprocess.run(["mysql", "-u" + mdb_usr, "-p" + mdb_pwd, "database < " + file.sql])
subprocess.run(["mysql -u" + mdb_usr + " -p" + mdb_pwd + "database < " + file.sql], shell = True)
```

But none of them seems to work.
Without the `< file.sql`, I can get the script to work, but I can't seem to get the sql to execute. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could try with `from subprocess import Popen`

Comment: If I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187984/9066313), that wouldn't help

Comment: `p = Popen(cmd, close_fds=True, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE);
    p.stdin.write(smoke);
    answer = p.communicate()[0];
    return answer` <<-- Try it.

Comment: Brilliant. Works (although no idea why or how), except that I need to now escape 1 character in the pwd string. Would there be a way to avoid that, so I don't have to remember for when I change the password?

Comment: It works by starting a sub-process (fork+exec), and feeding smoke to its stdin. It then sucks stdout until EOF. The subprocess then has ceased to exist, and the main process can continue. WRT the pwd (password?) : It is up to your code what to pass to the child process.