# How do I execute a file but keep the python code running?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am wondering how I can execute an app via the python code but keep the code running?

Here is an example:

**File1.py**

```py
from time import sleep
print("File1 has started")
sleep(3)
print("File1 has ended")
```

**main.py**

```py
from time import sleep
print("main.py has started")
# start the File1.py here
sleep(2)
print("main.py is still running")
sleep(2)
print("main.py has ended")
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
>> main.py has started
>> File1 has started
>> main.py is still running
>> File1 has ended
>> main.py has ended
```

And is it possible to execute the files with the standard app that is assigned to the app?
Example:

- If someone has the default program for ".txt" Word, then word should open that file
- If someone has the default program for ".txt" Notepad, then notepad should open that file.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep a Python script output window open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open)

Comment: I think you are supposed to ask one thing at a time and also put at least minimal effort to search for an already existing solution to your question. Seems like this is it for the second part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-os-application-in-python-both-in-windows-and-mac-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to organize the code in `File1.py` into a function, like this:

```
from time import sleep

def file_one_process():
    print("File1 has started")
    sleep(3)
    print("File1 has ended")
```

The you can call the function by importing the module at the top of `main.py` and calling the function, like this:

```
import File1

File1.file_one_process()
```

This produces the following output in the terminal:

> File1 has started
>
> `(sleeps/pauses for 3 seconds, doesn't print anything)`
>
> File1 has ended

If you wanted to intertwine the prints of `main.py` and `File1.py` Al you have to do is create multiple functions for each of the prints in `main.py` and `File1.py`, then call them in the order you want.

If you aren't dealing with a Python file, (for example, a `mov` file) then you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-os-application-in-python-both-in-windows-and-mac-os). You can use this code to run a file called `example.mov`.

```
import subprocess, os, platform

if platform.system() == 'Darwin':       # macOS
    subprocess.call(('open', "example.mov"))

elif platform.system() == 'Windows':    # Windows
    os.startfile("example.mov")

else:                                   # linux variants
    subprocess.call(('xdg-open', "example.mov"))
```

This isn't my code, it's [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435669/20585541).

Comment: Yeah, but what if the file is a `.mov` file? And my standard program for these is DaVinci Resolve? Can I open the `.mov` file using the standard program but keep the code running?

Comment: @Tousend1000 Ah, I see. Your question showed a Python program, so I figured my answer should how to do that with Python. I will look to see if I can find anything on this on the internet.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `subprocess.Popen` so that opening the file does not block python's code? I believe that's closer to OP's intent.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `subprocess.Popen`, are you sure it exists?

Comment: @BentheCoder See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187984/7585848. TLDR: it's similar to `call`, except returns immediately and runs the command in background.