# run streamlit from python script

Tags: python, browser, infinite-loop, streamlit

I'm trying to run streamlit out of my python script with the following command:

os.system('streamlit run 'r'G:\Python\Projekte\Userausgabe\1.3_Userausgabe.py')

When I run my script, it works as intended and opens streamlit in my browser...
but unfortunately, it doesn't stop. It continues opening windows and only stops, when I stop running the script.

I'm quite new into programming, started with Python 4 weeks ago and I didn't find anything helpful on the internet so far.

Has anyone of you ever stumbled across the same error or know any advice?

Many thanks in advance!

I tried

os.system('exit')

or

exit()

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `subprocess` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3) instead of `os.system`:

```py
from subprocess import run

process = run(["streamlit", "run", r"G:\Python\Projekte\Userausgabe\1.3_Userausgabe.py"])
```

It is the recommended way to execute systems calls and monitor/redirect outputs (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187984/13339621))

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I will keep it in mind. But unfortunately the error still occures.

Comment: I can run this as `.\main.exe` in the terminal, but when double clicking the same executable from the file browser I can see a terminal window open for a split second which immediately closes again, and nothing else happens. How do I keep the process alive?