# Run linux command from python which needs user input

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-2.7, openssl

I have following python code:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(["openssl","genrsa","-aes256","-out","ise.key.pem","2048"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
inputdata="123456"
p.communicate(input=inputata)
p.communicate(input=inputata)
```

output of above code is:

```
    pan@pan:~/python-scripts$ Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
........................+++
...................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Enter pass phrase for ise.key.pem:
User interface error
140617148802712:error:0906906F:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_write_bio:read key:pem_lib.c:379:
```

I want that input should be give by python there should not be any user interaction :

I know certificate can be generated by python pyOpenSSL library but I want to use normal linux command

**My python version is**:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "enter code here`license" for more information.
```

I saw following link but it didn't help

[Python execute command line,sending input and reading output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673185/python-execute-command-line-sending-input-and-reading-output)

If you run the command in shell it runs as below:

```
pan@pan:~/python-scripts$ openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ise.key.pem 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
..............................................................+++
..+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Enter pass phrase for ise.key.pem:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for ise.key.pem:
```

Comment: shell=True allows to work around the wrong entering of your process: list of arguments should be `["openssl","genrsa","-aes256","-out","ise.key.pem","2048"]`. But the real issue is that piping input to a password entering routine doesn't always work. You have to generate a keyboard event at a lower level.

Comment: I suggest that you try the above, then [edit] your question to remove the useless part about shell=True which makes your question twofold.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/165662/8765205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In his comment, Jean-François Fabre is right about this:

> But the real issue is that piping input to a password entering routine doesn't always work.

But not about this:

> You have to generate a keyboard event at a lower level.

Though it would be true in general, in the case at hand the command [`openssl genrsa …`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/genrsa.html) offers the option `-passout stdin` to [*read the password from standard input*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl.html):

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ise.key.pem -passout stdin 2048
```

So, this Python script works:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(["openssl","genrsa","-aes256","-out","ise.key.pem",
                    "-passout","stdin","2048"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
inputdata="123456"
p.communicate(input=inputdata)
```

Note that one cannot call [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) with *timeout=None* more than once, since it waits *for process to terminate*. But it isn't necessary either, because with `-passout stdin` the command doesn't ask for verifying, thus no need to enter the pass phrase a second time.

Comment: How to generate a keyboard event at a lower level?

I tried "openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ise.key.pem -passout stdin 2048" but it didn't work

Comment: @Pankaj Sheoran - See the expanded answer. To _generate a keyboard event at a lower level_ would be far more cumbersome and far less portable.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't like subprocess for this kind of tasks ... I would prefer to use pexpect to emulate human behaviour (typing in data ... and so on).

This one is a rough example to do the job

```
import pexpect

def main():
        inputdata="123456"
        c = pexpect.spawn("/usr/bin/openssl", ["genrsa","-aes256","-out","ise.key.pem","2048"])
        c.expect("Enter.*:")
        c.sendline(inputdata)
        c.expect("Verifying.*:")
        c.sendline(inputdata)
        c.expect(pexpect.EOF)
        c.close()
        c.kill(0)
        print "Done"

if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```